# Changed shifters and chain isn't in same spot

Tags: mountain-bike, derailleur-rear, shifting

My friend changed out the shifters on his bike and his rear derailleur isn't on the right sprocket based on what his shifter says. How can you fix this?

Comment: We can't fix this, but you can.   Check out this answer  bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32693/bike-wont-shift-into-2-largest-rear-cogs-lowest-gears/

Comment: The derailer/cable/shifter needs to be adjusted.  (Though if he changed the shifters there is some chance that he got the wrong ones, and there is no adjustment that will make things line up.)

Answer (score 1):

This happens everytime one replaces a component of the drivetrain since the original cable position is rarely restored.
He needs to do something called indexing the gears. It is a common procedure and there are many good tutorials online explaining how to do it much better than I could. Here is one I'd trust-